# Definition of prime ideal in Gerald J. Janusz' book "Algebraic Number Fields"

Tags: abstract-algebra

On page 2 he says:

Definition:

An ideal P of a commutative Ring R is prime, if $a,b\in R$ and $ ab\in P$ implies either $a\in P$ or $b\in P$.

R is said to be commutative with unity and no zero divisors at the beginning of the chapter.

Doesn't he forget to say that $P\neq R$ in this definition?

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book but I can comment that the ring $R$ itself should not be considered as a prime ideal.